# Use array.reduce() for array of characters

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of characters (arr) and a string (J), I wanted to use the `array.reduce()` method to count the number of characters of the array (arr) present in the string J.

Below is the code which shows how I am using array.reduce() method,

```
let val = arr.reduce((count , ch) => {
    return J.includes(ch) ? count + 1 : count
});
```

But when I tried with sample value as,

```
arr = ​​​​​[ 'a', 'A', 'A', 'S', 'S' ]​​​​​;

J = 'aA';
```

I get the anser as

```
val = 'a11'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `initialValue` in second parameter of `.reduce()` as mentioned in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Syntax)

```
arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])
```

```js
var arr = [ 'a', 'A', 'A', 'S', 'S' ];
var J = 'aA';
let val = arr.reduce((count , ch) => {
    return J.includes(ch) ? count + 1 : count
}, 0);
console.log(val);
```